# HTML native lazyloading slows down image loading

Tags: javascript, cordova, lazy-loading

I'm using the [native `lazyload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading) attribute to lazyload images in a [Cordova app](https://cordova.apache.org/) but from time to time the images don't load quickly after they're in the viewport (can take up to 4s after they're in the viewport before they load). This is inconsistent, and it *seems* related to the presence of another ongoing network request. In chrome dev tools I can see that the images get a priority of "Low", and the slow load seems to happen when there's another request running at the same time with a priority of "High". Is there a way to prevent this? Resource hints such as `<link rel="preload" href="my-img.jpeg" as="image">` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)) won't work for me because these are dynamically loaded images, so I can't have them loaded ahead of time. It seems [Google's Priority Hints](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/priority-hints) feature will be what I need (`importance="high"` and `importance="low"`), but it's still an Origin Trial so I can't use it in production. Are there other ways I can increase the load priority of lazyloaded images when using the native `lazyload` attribute? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a fan of lazy-loading images for just this reason

Comment: Yeah I'm now learning the hard way. Any ideas for how to work around it?

Comment: If you are set on using lazy load, you could use a cache on the backend. On the front-end, I recommend you look into indexedDB

Comment: Preloading with `<link rel...` beats the purpose of lazyloading anyway...

Comment: @ControlAltDel Can you explain some more on how your IndexedDB suggestion would work?